# ¿Como puedo comparar 2 cadenas String en un validator xml de Struts2?

Tags: xml, java-ee, struts

Saludos a la comunidad, mi pregunta es como puedo comparar dos cadenas dentro de un xml validator de struts2, estoy haciendo las prubeas de esta forma, pero no consigo recuperar el error.

```
<validators>
<field name="usuario.user">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <param name="trim">true</param>
        <message>Ingrese su Nombre de Usuario</message>
    </field-validator>
    <field-validator type="expression">
        <param name="expression">usuario.user != "admin"</param>
        <message>Usuario Incorrecto! Verifique</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
<field name="usuario.pass">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <param name="trim">true</param>
        <message>Ingrese su contraseña</message>
    </field-validator>
    <field-validator type="expression">
        <param name="expression">usuario.pass != "1234"</param>
        <message>Contraseña Incorrecta! Verifique</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

el primer mensaje si lo arroja con exito si el campo esta vacio, pero el siguiente no lo valida correctamente.
si existe alguna forma mejor, se los agradeceria un mundo.
Saludos
Josue Martinez

Answer (score 0):

Navegando en el mar enorme de internet consegui la respuesta, para el problema de la siguiente forma:

```
introducir el código aqu<validators>
<field name="usuario.user">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <param name="trim">true</param>
        <message>Ingrese su Nombre de Usuario</message>
    </field-validator>
    **<field-validator type="fieldexpression">
        <param name="expression"><![CDATA[usuario.user == 'admin']]></param>**
        <message>Usuario Incorrecto! Verifique</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
<field name="usuario.pass">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <param name="trim">true</param>
        <message>Ingrese su contraseña</message>
    </field-validator>
    **<field-validator type="fieldexpression">
        <param name="expression"><![CDATA[usuario.pass == '1234']]></param>
        <message>Contraseña Incorrecta! Verifique</message>
    </field-validator>**
</field>
```

Para si a alguien pueda servirle esta solucion, usando como fuente el siguiente blog.
https://www.codesd.com/item/struts-2-ognl-comparing-two-string-values-in-valid-xml.html